# PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

```
CREATE TABLE member(
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_name varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_surname varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
    birthdate DATE,
    phone varchar2(11),
    mail varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    member_password varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    address varchar2(255) not null,
    status number(1),
    role_id number(10) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE item(
    item_id number(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_id number(11) ,
    publish_date DATE,
    is_occupied NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    publisher_id number(11) NOT NULL
    
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE reservation(
    reservation_id number(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    member_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    item_id number(11) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    status number(1)
);
```

AND TRIGGER :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER prereservation
BEFORE INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Access the member information using the member id
    SELECT * INTO :new.member
    FROM member
    WHERE member_id = :new.member_id;
    
    -- Check the status of the member
    IF :new.member.status != 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Member has an inactive status');
    END IF;
    
    -- Check if the member id is null in the item table
    SELECT * INTO :new.item
    FROM item
    WHERE item.member_id = :new.member_id;
    
    IF :new.member_id IS NULL THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Member does not have any items');
    END IF;
    
    -- Check that the start date is before the end date
    IF :new.start_date >= :new.end_date THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Start date must be before end date');
    END IF;
END;
```

In order to make a reservation, the member must be active, so the status in the member table should be 1 . While making a reservation, if the member _ id in the item table is null, it means that the item is not in the user. If it has a member_id other than null, a user is using that item. And the reservation start date and end date difference should be made. However, I am getting an error.

In order to make a reservation, the member must be active, so the status in the member table should be 1 . While making a reservation, if the member _ id in the item table is null, it means that the item is not in the user. If it has a member_id other than null, a user is using that item. And the reservation start date and end date difference should be made. However, I am getting an error.

Comment: you need to declare all variables first see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52700

Answer (score 2):

The `new` part refers to [a pseudorecord](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E), representing the row being inserted (in this case) to the `reservation` table.

When you refer to `:new.member`, the `member` has to be a column in that table. The error is because it is not.

You're trying to check the member's status, so you should be querying that directly into a local variable, which you need to declare:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER prereservation
BEFORE INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_status member.status%TYPE;
BEGIN
    -- Access the member information using the member id
    SELECT status INTO l_status
    FROM member
    WHERE member_id = :new.member_id;
    
    -- Check the status of the member
    IF l_status != 0 THEN
    ...
```

So I've added the `DECLARE` keyword; declared an `l_status` variable; changed the query to get the just the `status` value from the `member` table and store that in the new variable; and changed the check to look at that variable.

You're doing something similar with `item`, but here you need to count the number of items, and check if that is zero:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER prereservation
BEFORE INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_status member.status%TYPE;
    l_item_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Access the member information using the member id
    SELECT status INTO l_status
    FROM member
    WHERE member_id = :new.member_id;
    
    -- Check the status of the member
    IF l_status != 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Member has an inactive status');
    END IF;
    
    -- Check if the member id is in the item table
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_item_count
    FROM item
    WHERE item.member_id = :new.member_id;
    
    IF l_item_count = 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Member does not have any items');
    END IF;
    ...
```

Or possibly (it's a little unclear) you want to check if the item in the reservation has the same member:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER prereservation
BEFORE INSERT ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_status member.status%TYPE;
    l_item_member_id item.member_id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    -- Access the member information using the member id
    SELECT status INTO l_status
    FROM member
    WHERE member_id = :new.member_id;
    
    -- Check the status of the member
    IF l_status != 0 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Member has an inactive status');
    END IF;
    
    -- Check if the member id is not in the item table
    SELECT member_id INTO l_item_member_id
    FROM item
    WHERE item.item_id = :new.item_id;
    
    IF l_item_member_id IS NULL OR l_item_member_id != :new.member_id THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error: Member does not have any items');
    END IF;
    ...
```

The meaning of `member_id` in the `item` table is unclear though.

Comment: but i am facing a problem. Logically, when a member reserves the book, that item should not be booked again until that member gets that item or the 15-day reservation period must expire.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, it's hard to read, and I'm not sure what it's supposed to be showing. You seem to be adding a new condition which isn't in your question, so you should probably ask a new one, explaining the logic fully. I'm not sure that's something you should be trying to check in a trigger though.